# how to update an app in play store?

Tags: android

I want to update an app in play store.I used same keystore for update also.And package name also same.I increase the version code and version name.But still it's showing the following errors

Upload failed

You uploaded an APK that is signed with a different certificate to your previous APKs. You must use the same certificate.

Your existing APKs are signed with the certificate(s) with fingerprint(s):
[ SHA1: BF:09:58:1D:BC:80:A1:A1:29:B4:F2:B5:D2:C1:A5:01:C0:43:B3:A8 ]
and the certificate(s) used to sign the APK you uploaded have fingerprint(s):
[ SHA1: 8C:E1:24:FE:74:6E:D1:72:07:E3:93:07:23:09:C7:0B:79:82:6A:2D ]

How to resolve this???????????

Comment: The error message is pretty clear. Use the same certificate (key) for signing as for the previous APKs.

Comment: Whatever i gave to old one same thing i'm using now.

Answer (score 0):

The same keystore does not mean the same key. check if you use the same key.

To sign an apk in release mode, you have to provide

- keystore
- keystore password
- key
- key password

Comment: Ya I gave the same key and password.